# Error while running multiprocessing Queue in Gramine: No such file or directory

Tags: multiprocessing, queue

I met an error while I running a program in Gramine, I hope someone can answer it for me.
Hear are my files' detail.
This is my mainfest file:

```
loader.entrypoint = "file:{{ gramine.libos }}"
libos.entrypoint = "{{ entrypoint }}"

loader.log_level = "debug"

loader.env.LD_LIBRARY_PATH = "/lib:/usr/lib:{{ arch_libdir }}:/usr/{{ arch_libdir }}"

loader.env.OMP_NUM_THREADS = "8"

loader.insecure__use_cmdline_argv = true
loader.insecure__use_host_env = true

sgx.nonpie_binary = true

fs.mounts = [
  { uri = "file:{{ gramine.runtimedir() }}", path = "/lib" },
  { uri = "file:{{ arch_libdir }}", path = "{{ arch_libdir }}" },
  { uri = "file:/usr", path = "/usr" },
  { uri = "file:/etc", path = "/etc" },
  { uri = "file:{{ pillow_path }}", path = "{{ pillow_path }}" },

  { type = "tmpfs", path = "/tmp" },
]

sgx.enclave_size = "1G"
sgx.max_threads = 32

sgx.edmm_enable = {{ 'true' if env.get('EDMM', '0') == '1' else 'false' }}
sgx.trusted_files = [
  "file:{{ gramine.libos }}",
  "file:{{ entrypoint }}",
  "file:{{ gramine.runtimedir() }}/",
  "file:{{ arch_libdir }}/",
  "file:/usr/{{ arch_libdir }}/",
  "file:{{ python.stdlib }}/",
  "file:{{ python.distlib }}/",
  "file:{{ pillow_path }}",
  "file:{{ python.get_path('stdlib', vars={'installed_base': '/usr/local'}) }}/",

  "file:test.py",
]
```

This is my program file:

```
import multiprocessing

def worker(queue):
    item = queue.get()
    print("Worker received:", item)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(queue,))
    process.start()

    item = "Hello, multiprocessing!"
    queue.put(item)

    process.join()

    while not queue.empty():
        item = queue.get()
        print("Item in queue:", item)
```

And this is error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py", line 103, in Queue
    return Queue(maxsize, ctx=self.get_context())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 42, in __init__
    self._rlock = ctx.Lock()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py", line 68, in Lock
    return Lock(ctx=self.get_context())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 162, in __init__
    SemLock.__init__(self, SEMAPHORE, 1, 1, ctx=ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 57, in __init__
    sl = self._semlock = _multiprocessing.SemLock(
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Maybe the multiprocessing Queue is not supported in Gramine, but I want to know actually.
Hope someone can tell me, thank you!